# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) using list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run this code below:

```
namelist =[[('mixamorig:Head', 'head')],
           [('mixamorig:Neck', 'neck_01')]]
for name, newname in namelist:
    pb = obj.pose.bones.get(name)
    if pb is None:
        continue
    pb.name = newname
```

But it gives this error:

```
  for name, newname in namelist:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I've tried to replace the `[` with `(` or add different enclosures but nothing worked, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why you wrap the tuples in a list? Just remove the inner lists: `namelist =[('mixamorig:Head', 'head'),
('mixamorig:Neck', 'neck_01')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a list of lists of tuples, not a list of tuples. So you'd need something like:

```
for item in namelist:
   for name, newname in item:
      # do something
```

(or change your data as written in the comment above)